# SELECT sql row when value changes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with a sql query.

I'm using MariaDB. I have a table with several fields and I want to select the rows when they change values.

For example:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| time_stamp | G1.state | G2.state |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 1433717821 | 3        | 1        |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 1433717881 | 3        | 1        |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 1433717942 | 5        | 1        |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

Here I need to get the time_stamp when 3 changes to 5. I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT a.`time_stamp`, a.`G1.state`, `G2.state` 
FROM `regs` AS `a` 
WHERE ((a.`G1.Estado` <> 
    (SELECT b.`G1.state` 
     FROM `regs` AS `b` 
     WHERE a.time_stamp > b.time_stamp 
     ORDER BY b.time_stamp DESC 
     LIMIT 1)) OR
   (a.`G2.state` <>
    (SELECT b.`G2.state`
     FROM `regs` AS `b`
     WHERE a.time_stamp > b.time_stamp 
     ORDER BY b.time_stamp DESC 
     LIMIT 1))) AND
    (a.time_stamp >= 1433159549) AND (a.time_stamp < 1433677949)
ORDER BY a.time_stamp ASC
```

However it just takes too long to run, it takes 50.96 sec and I need it a lot faster (hopefully less than a second). It analyzes around 10k values. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (E.g. LIMIT is product specific...)

Comment: So with those 3 rows, you only want the last one returned?

Comment: Please, add what indexes do you have for your table.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB (edited). I have more rows, it's just so it's easier to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables to track changes in `G1.state` or `G2.state` columns:

```
SELECT time_stamp, `G1.state`, `G2.state`
FROM (
SELECT time_stamp, `G1.state`, `G2.state`,
       IF (@g1 IS NOT NULL AND @g1 <> `G1.state`, 
           IF(@g1:= `G1.state`, 1, 1), 
           IF(@g1:= `G1.state`, 0, 0)) AS g1Changed,
       IF (@g2 IS NOT NULL AND @g2 <> `G2.state`, 
           IF(@g2:= `G2.state`, 1, 1), 
           IF(@g2:= `G2.state`, 0, 0)) AS g2Changed           
FROM mytable, (SELECT @g1:= NULL, @g2:= NULL) AS vars
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC ) t
WHERE g1Changed = 1 OR g2Changed = 1
```

This query might perform better since no correlated subqueries are used.

**Note:** according to [**MariaDB documentation**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/user-defined-variables/):

> It is unsafe to read a user-defined variable and set its value in the same statement (unless the command is SET), because the order of these actions is undefined.

To overcome this problem nested conditionals are used: `@g1` or `@g2` are *first* compared against `G1.state`, `G2.state` values respectively, and *then* set in order to be compared again when the next record is fetched.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e60/9)

Comment: Your query works perfectly, but I have a question. The first time I ran it in the console, it returned zero values. However, on the second try it had some values on it. The same thing happened when I ran it using php, if I run it once, I get zero values, however, running it twice fixes it. Is it because of the variables that need to first be declared?

Comment: @Comum Try `FROM mytable, (SELECT @g1:= NULL, @g2:= NULL) AS vars`. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e60/9)

Comment: Kudos for keeping the calculations for each value in a single `if` expression.  MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions for `select`, and you have the right expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from regs a
Where time_stamp=
     (Select Max(time_stamp) from regs
      Where time_stamp< a.time_stamp)
  and 'g1.state' <> a.'g1.staTE'
order by a.time_stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your query with indexes.  The best index is

```
regs(time_stamp, `G1.state`, `G2.state`)
```

Note:  it is *really* bad practice to use a character such as `.` in a column name.

Comment: ditto on use of the period

Comment: yeah, when I get this working, I'm starting to change all the dots.